# How to get react-router-redux redirect URL in SSR

Tags: redux, history.js, react-router-redux

I'm using `react-router-redux@5.0.0-alpha.9` and I haven't found a workaround to capture the `<Redirect>` URL on Server Side Rendering.

Use cases:

- Not identified user tries to access a secure route, `<Redirect>` sends the user to login route.
- Already logged in user tries to access login form, `<Redirect>` sends the user to main private route.

Right now the redirect is happening in the browser but it would be great to provide a way for capturing `<Redirect>` URL and send a proper redirect from the server.

I would love to do something similar to the `<StaticRouter>` solution (using `context` with `<ConnectedRouter>`)

```
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';

const context = {};
const app = renderToString(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history} isSSR context={context}>
      <Application />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
);

if (context.url) {
  const HTTP_FOUND = 302;

  res.writeHead(HTTP_FOUND, { Location: context.url });
  res.end();
}
```

I've tried `history.listen` as well and it's not firing the location change.

```
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createMemoryHistory';

const context = {};
const history = createHistory({
  initialEntries: [req.url], // req.url comes from express server
  initialIndex: 0,
});

history.listen(location => {
  // this gets never called
  console.log('History changed!', location);
});

const app = renderToString(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history} isSSR>
      <Application />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`history.listen` is not fired because the `<Redirect>` component, when used on the server during SSR and with `ConnectedRouter`, does not do anything due to `ConnectedRouter` not providing the required `staticContext`.

Please have a look at https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/5323 for a discussion about this.

Seems that the proper solution is to not use `ConnectedRouter` during SSR at all, but rather use the `StaticRouter` and dispatching your own initial  `LOCATION_CHANGE` action to have the store in sync with the current location.

See https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5333#issuecomment-315737132 for a detailed comment about this.

Comment: After trying a lot I managed to get this working with both `react-router-redux` actions and `<Redirect>` using the solution proposed by williamoliveira [github issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4892#issuecomment-336634998).

Thank you, Stefan, for helping me go in the right direction.